# Does ls provide information about NFS permissions?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, nfs

When writing to NFS directories remotely, what would the permissions of files written be, when both the client and the server use Linux?

Does `ls -l` show file permissions as seen by the NFS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions are the same as they would be if you wrote to a local directory. So that would generally depend on your umask, unless the program sets permissions explicitly. And yes, `ls -l` on the client should show the permissions as they are on the server, unless you have a non-standard server.

Comment: Unless you are accessing them as root user, where the server usually maps UID 0 to some other UID (called root squash).